# textarea not providing html tags

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

This may be a very simple and stupid question, but it's so simple that I don't know what I did wrong.

I'm trying to get the content of a textarea while retaining the formatting (breakline, spaces, etc). but when i tried to post the form, there was no html tags to be found. all I got was plain text.

when I type in the textarea like this:

```
first line



after 3 br
```

I expected the result of `echo $foo;` to be something like this:

```
first&nbsp;line
&lt;br/&gt;gt;
&lt;br/&gt;gt;
&lt;br/&gt;gt;
after&nbsp;3&nbsp;br
```

but instead, the result of `echo $foo;` was still like this:

```
first line



after 3 br
```

this is the `display.php`:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <textarea name="foo"><?php echo set_value('foo'); ?></textarea>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

this is the controller:

```
function form_foo()
{
  $foo = $this->input->post('foo');
  if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  {
    $foo = stripslashes($foo);
  }
  $foo = htmlentities($foo);
  echo $foo;
  $this->load->view('display', $this->data);
}
```

what did I do wrong?

P.S : I'm using codeigniter 3.0 and PHP 5.6.15

Comment: `<textarea>` content **is** just plain text - why would you expect otherwise?

Comment: u can use ckeditor

Comment: When you echo $foo, did you perform a view source to see what was actually being output... It's a good thing to do...

Comment: The <textarea> element allows to insert and edit _text_, not _markup_.

Comment: @CD001 how do I get the breakline tags? I need to store it in the database afterwards..

Comment: @TimBrownlaw yes, I tried to perform a view source and it didn't show any breakline tags. how do I get the breakline tags?

Comment: Use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Comment: @dapidmini Remove this line ```$foo = htmlentities($foo);``` No need to pass through ```htmlentites()```

Comment: You don't (generally) want `<br>` tags - they're semantically irrelevant - type the HTML you *do* want into the `<textarea>` or use a WYSIWYG editor like TinyMCE or CKEditor. As an aside the **magicquotes** feature was removed in PHP 5.4 - if you're still checking/using it you really should update your version of PHP (or move to a better host).

Comment: @roberto06 CMIIW, but if we have to encode everything from the textarea ourselves, doesn't that mean the htmlentities function isn't needed at all?

Comment: @mi6crazyheart when I remove the htmlentities, all the breaklines from the textarea was replaced by a single space..

Comment: thank you all who replied to this question. I found the solution was just use nl2br when showing the data on the page as @roberto06 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
function form_foo()
{
    $foo = $this->input->post('foo');
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $foo = stripslashes($foo);
    }

    //$foo = htmlentities($foo);

    echo $foo;
    $this->load->view('display', $this->data);
}
```

Comment: when i remove the htmlentities part, all the breaklines was replaced by a single space..

Comment: Ok, can you tell me why you want to show those line break in form of normal TEXT characters rather than HTML characters? I'm just trying to understand about your use case.

Comment: I thought <br /> was an HTML character? I just wanted to store the breaklines into the database.. I thought the only way was to encode <br /> into &lt;br/&gt; or something

Comment: In your current format of the code when data getting saved in table.. is it not saving in this ```&lt;br/&gt;gt;```` ?

Comment: no. the field in the table contains just like was shown in the textarea. the line breaks exists but not shown as the literal characters <br/> or \n. anyway, I settled for using nl2br when showing the data from database, which does what I expected it to

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [`contenteditable`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp)?

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

This can turn `<div>` into editable area but without style. You need to style them additionally.

Here is my CSS solution

```
[contentEditable=true] {
    white-space: pre;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    min-height: 6em;
    max-height: 12em;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    outline: none !important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

> Beware of dealing with the HTML tags.

See reference [contenteditable](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp).